# Can't login to Django Admin with custom User Model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users, django-login, django-custom-user

I create a custom model for User, By this I can create superuser from command line, and its create successfully. But when I trying to login to Django admin with created Super user its show me This error [image]

@property
def is_staff(self):
return self.staff

@property
def is_superuser(self):
return self.superuser

@property
def is_active(self):
return self.active

These property also set True

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        creates a user with given email and password
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('user must have a email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(self._db)
    return user

def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
    """
    creates a user with staff permissions
    """
    user = self.create_user(
        email=email,
        password=password
    )
    user.staff = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    """
    creates a superuser with email and password
    """
    user = self.create_user(
        email=email,
        password=password
    )
    user.staff = True
    user.superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # <- admin user, not super user
superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # <- super user


USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # <- email and password are required by default

class Meta:
    app_label = "account_app"
    db_table = "users"

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def get_full_name(self):
    return str(self.email)

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    """Does the user has a specific permission"""
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_lable):
    """Does the user has permission to view a specific app"""
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    """Is the user a staff member"""
    return self.staff

@property
def is_superuser(self):
    """Is the user a admin member"""
    return self.superuser

@property
def is_active(self):
    """Is the user active"""
    return self.active

# hook the user manager to objects
objects = UserManager()
```

**settings.py** where I change for Custom User Model

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dashboard_app',
    'account_app',

]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account_app.User" # changes the built-in user model to ours

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SMSystem.wsgi.application'
```

Answer (score 0):

its set default value for `active = 0` need to set 1 or True

Comment: Can you please rephrase this answer? I did not get were I need to put active=1 or True. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Instead of password=None, change it to password. And pass 'password=password' together with 'username=username' into the create_user function as you see below:

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, username, password):
if not email:
raise ValueError('Please add an email address')
if not username:
raise ValueError('Please add an username')

```
    **user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(
    email), username=username, password=password)**

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(
    email), username=username, password=password)

        user.is_active = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Only users with `is_active` attribute `True` can log into the system.
Inside `createuser` method pass `active=True` or change default value of `active to True`

```
def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        creates a user with given email and password
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('user must have a email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        active=True, #Add this line
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(self._db)
    return user
```

--OR, change default value of active to true --

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    # change default value to True
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me: Rather than passing `password=password` into the self.model call in my `create_superuser` method, I called `user.set_password(password)`. After doing that, I was able to login.